# Reporting capabilities for automated tests using Selenium

Tags: selenium, bug-report, test-report

How can we add reporting capabilities to Selenium based UI automated testing, such as reports on failed and passed tests, recurring failed tests, etc.?

Comment: You could use jenkins for running the tests and creating reports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest combining Selenium with a test-runner like [jUnit](http://junit.org/) or [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html), then you can parse the results into a nice report with [Allure (also lists more test-runners)](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki).

The next step is to run all the test on each build, with a build-server like [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) and report broken build/tests with visual indicators.

- [Allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/) is a reporting framework to parse xUnit test results, looks pretty nice
- [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) has reporting, read this blog post to get started: http://learn-automation.com/generate-reports-selenium-using-testng-xslt/

Comment: If you are using C# NUnit is also a good source for parsing a test report

Answer (score 0):

> This answer is for users who are using PyCharm/want to explore PyCharm.

For Selenium based tests, PyCharm allows you to obtain the test results. If you click the `Explore Test Results` option at the `Test Runner` tab, of Pycharm, a nice HTML of your tests results open up.

It allows you to take results in following three formats :

- HTML
- XML
- Custom , apply XSL template.

**To view results in browser :**

Select the `Open Exported File` check box

This will automatically open your test results in your default browser.